# Small Caps doesn't work with Twitter Bootstrap on Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this very simple markup

```
<h1>
    <a href="#">
        My Title
    </a>
</h1>
```

and this CSS

```
h1 {
   font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

Here it is rendered on a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XP9jQ/3/).

The issue comes from using Twitter Bootstrap. The text renders like it has no `font-variant` defined.

I'm sure that Bootstrap is the cause, since when you remove it, the text renders as expected. Any ideas or workaround for this?

I'm trying it on Chrome 26.0.1410.64

### Bootstrap ON

[image: Bootstrap ON]

### Bootstrap OFF

[image]

Comment: The jsfiddle works for me. (Firefox 20)

Comment: Demonstrate that including bootstrap your `font-variant` disappears.

Comment: @John go to the JSFiddle I've posted and remove the bootstrap reference. Run it and you'll see that it renders properly

Comment: @erenon I've tried on IE 10 and worked surprisingly fine :) So it's a Chrome issue

Comment: I have no problem in both: Firefox and Chrome (Ubuntu 13.04). :-) Can you add two screen shots?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try setting:

```
text-rendering: auto;
```

Here's an updated jsFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/XP9jQ/6/

The problem appeared because Twitter Bootstrap has this rule:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { text-rendering: optimizelegibility; }.
```

text-rendering: optimizelegibility; doesnt play well with small-caps in Google Chrome for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

See [this thread](http://www.voyagebc.com/support/topic/cannot-apply-font-variant-to-h-tags/).

As strange as it is, the issue is actually **Chrome**, and the fact that you are putting the `font-variant: small-caps;` on a tag which resides inside an `H#` tag.

Apparently, Chrome is unable to honor `small-caps` on `H#` tags and their descendants at this time. Please take a look at [this update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/XP9jQ/7/) to see what I mean.

You might have better luck altering your HTML to simply style a `<span>`, `<p>`, or `<div>` element to look like an `<h1>` element in this case - because Chrome will then honor your `small-caps` style.

**Update:**

Seeing the others' posts - I've noticed that the `text-rendering: auto` actually forces Chrome back into proper rendering. [This update to the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/XP9jQ/8/) demonstrates this fix. Credit for the workaround to [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/565565/martin).

Comment: Excellent answer man! I have to give the points to @Martin since he answered first. Thanks for your excellent answer

Comment: Good. :) His answer taught me the trick, too. Kudos to @Martin.

Comment: Thanks. The problem appeared because Twitter Bootstrap has this rule: h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}. text-rendering: optimizelegibility; doesnt play well with small-caps in Google Chrome for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

The setting `font-variant: small-caps` almost never produces real small caps. Instead, it makes browsers use fake small caps simply by reducing the size of normal capital letters. This can be seen e.g. in the “Bootstrap OFF” screenshot: the “small caps” have too small stroke width, simply because they are of different font size than normal capital letters.

So apart from the technical problem that prevents some browser from using fake small caps and that might have been solved, the basic problem remains: you don’t get true small caps. To get them, you would need a typeface that contains small caps, some additional markup, some advanced CSS rules (like `font-feature-settings`) that take small caps into use, and a modern browser that supports those CSS constructs. And most fonts that are commonly available in people’s computers don’t have real small caps.

The morale is: use other typographic devices instead of small caps.